# Are feature requests on StackExchange Meta considered duplicates here?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a particularly good feature request on the [StackExchange Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag).

Is requesting it here considered a duplicate of the one on the StackExchange Meta Site or not?

On one hand, it could be considered a duplicate because the StackExchange Meta applies to all sites on the network, and so it being approved will allow it on all sites.

On the other hand, it might not be considered a duplicate, because technically the two different meta sites are different communities.

Do we consider feature requests on StackExchange Meta duplicates if they are posted here?

Comment: Whether or not it's technically a "duplicate", there isn't really any point in duplicating that request here. The whole network shares essentially all of the code that handles markdown processing and post rendering, so that request applies to the whole network.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, requesting it here is a duplicate, and unnecessary effort on your part. Feature requests get a lot more traffic on MSE than they do here, and are much more likely to be seen by SE employees that could actually do anything about it.

Instead of posting it here, add your voice/vote to the question on MSE and help it get more traction, or add arguments for it that haven't been shared before. It will be more effective than posting it again here.